# How to monitor and set 1 / 0 if the value is incrementing compared to previous value in Node-red

Tags: javascript, node-red

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCHkB.jpg)I need to write a logic in Nodered to monitor a signal coming from external (Modbus analog point in my case) and set another variable 0 or 1 if the actual point value is incrementing compared to previous value.

EX:
Variable A is being read from external communication every 5 seconds.
I need to set Variable B value as 1 if Variable A value is higher than previously read value, if not I need to set Variable B value as 0.

I tried using Filter node in Node red but am unable to use condition pass/ fail result to set another variable B value.

Please can someone help me out

Here is how flow looks like (please check the attached picture). I am doing a Modbus read and combining multiple registers to get 32 bit values and then trying to use Filter block to see if a specific register value is greater than previous value. Based on this pass/ fail condition, I want to set a flag Pass/Fail to raise an alarm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjYhf.png)

Comment: You need to show us how you configured the filter node and actual examples of the input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated the description to have code flow picture and other details, please can someone help me here